# NoReverseMatch at /blogs/ 'post' is not a registered namespace

Tags: python, django

I have started a project with an app called `Post` with the purpose of making a `Blog` and after finishing it, I understood the importance of choosing an accurate name for each app so I decided to start a new application and call it blog but now I am trying to fix the errors of name changing.

So I fixed all errors except on which I don't know its source:

```
NoReverseMatch at /blogs/
'post' is not a registered namespace
```

I am not sure if it has to do with the Project's url

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
    .............]
```

Blog app urls.py

```
app_name = 'blog'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('blogs/', PostListView.as_view(), name='post-list'),
    path('blog/<slug:slug>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('new_blog/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
]
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/directions.html')

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "blog/post_list.html"
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 5

class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "blog/post_detail.html"

class PostCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content']
    success_url = '/'
    template_name = 'blog/post_form.html'  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    content = RichTextUploadingField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    ........................................

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is probably in one of your templates.

Check to see if you have added any link with href of something like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'post:url_name' %}"</a>
```

If yes, then replace the `post` word in the url with `blog`. 
This error comes because you have specified your `app_name`as `blog`, not `post`